# How do I make a pickpocket effect?

Tags: rec-room

I'm making a game where people can be a thief and everyone can sneak up on anyone in the room but I do not understand how the development team wants us to select players?

If the player is in the vicinity of another user I want to give players the option to pickpocket one another.

I want to have a system where when a player is close to one or more other players they can:

- select a particular player that is close to them, ideally in a discreet way.
- transfer some amount of data from that player to them (e.g. money in
  a player stat) to simulate pickpocketing.

Do we have any options to select players and make things happen? Is there any way possible to make an effect for pickpocketing?

Comment: You would have to be more specific. What do you mean when you say select players or pickpocketing effect? Describe exactly what you want to happen and when you want it to happen.

Comment: I would like to walk up to a player and pickpocket them? We have no options from what i see to make this happen.Im not understanding how much more detail you need.

Comment: When I ask about something that I find unclear or not detailed enough, it doesn't help if you use the exact same single word again. Try editing the question to explain the interactions and their result that you are looking for in simpler words.

Comment: This is the effect im trying to get. I want to walk up to a player and pickpocket that player. What else is needed? You are not explaining what you dont understand. Its very clear what i would like to see happen. Im not seeing any options to select players outright in our tabs for circuits or gadgets how do i make this effect happen?

Comment: You are telling me explain the interaction i am... The player walks up to another player in game and i would like something to happen when the player gets behind them.

Comment: Just so I understand correctly the exact functionality you're trying to achieve, let me try to restate what you're trying to do and you can correct me if I'm wrong:

You want to have a system where when a player is close to another they can:
- select a particular player that is close to them somehow
- transfer some amount of data from that player to them (e.g. money in a player stat) to simulate pickpocketing.

Is this correct?

Comment: @Echoleta yes this is correct. I just want to simulate pickpocketing in the exact fashion you describe.

Answer (score 2):

The way I would understand pickpocketing in Rec Room is this: One player holsters an object in one of the hip equip slots. Another player is able to grab that object from the hip equip slot.

How could this be implemented? By default other players cannot grab anything from a hip equip slot. So, to allow for the possibility of pickpocketing, you might have to holster an invisible object that is connected to a player trigger zone around it and a clamp gizmo which is connect to the actual object. Some circuits might be able to do the following: if another player enters the trigger zone, the clamp gizmo unclamps the object such that it can be grabbed. In case the object is not grabbed and the other player exits the trigger zone, the clamp might reclamp the object.

Obviously, things become more difficult if it should be possible to pickpocket the object from the thief.

Comment: Interesting idea. That would not allow the thief to pocket the item themselves right? Or maybe it could be forcefully spawned out of the other players holster? Not sure if that is actually possible.

Comment: They could pocket it but it wouldn't be possible to steal it from them (at least not in the same way).